# creating static methods VS autowiring and then calling methods

Tags: java, spring, performance

Generally in case of mapping(converting DTO's between database and frontend) we can use static methods.
It can also be achieved by autowiring a class(not static) and then calling the methods to convert DTO's.

I have been asked to improved performance and look into code quality, I wanted to know does this makes any difference if we use either of them..
As per my understanding autowiring will create a bean in spring context while the static method approach will leave it out for java to create an instance.

What should be the coding practice followed based on facts ?

Comment: I wanted to understand is there a best coding practice that should be followed(code quality)...should we call static methods or Autowire classes ?

Comment: In short - IoC gives more flexibility with comparable performance.You can have singleton with method, or static method - what is the difference? In terms of performance - almost none. However if you wish to test... autowired methods works much better.

Answer (score 0):

This might be too late for the TS/OP, but recent recommendations from Sonar tend to prefer the use static reference instead of autowiring if possible.